# Access ajax post form data at server side

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I'm trying to post some data along with the uploaded file. As a first go I tried to pass all the data which I hope to retrieve at server side as parameters. Even though I managed to retrieve the value for the parameter "Mode" correctly. I never receive a value for the parameter "file".  I don't know why?

Following is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReadFromExcel(HttpPostedFileBase file, bool Mode)
{
    // file is always null
    // Mode receives the correct values.
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ReadExcel").click(function () {

    var overwritefields = $("#overwritefields").is(":checked");


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ReadFromExcel',
        data: '{"file":"' + document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0] + '","Mode":"' + overwritefields + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            // Refresh data

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error occured, Please contact System Administrator. \n" + "Error: " + error.statusText);
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

Then I tried to access file via Request.File[0] which is successful upto some extend. But how can I retrieve value for other form data such as "Mode"?

Following is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReadFromExcel()
{
    var file = Request.Files[0].
    // file contains the correct value.
    // Unable to retrieve mode value though.
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ReadExcel").click(function () {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("FileUpload", document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0]);


    var overwritefields = $("#overwritefields").is(":checked");
    formData.append("Mode", overwritefields);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ReadFromExcel',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            // Refresh data

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error occured, Please contact System Administrator. \n" + "Error: " + error.statusText);
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

Following is my view:

```
@model IPagedList<Budget>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Import Budget Line Items From Excel";
var tooltip = new Dictionary<string, object>();
tooltip.Add("title", "Click to import budget line items from Excel");

int pageSize = 10;
string sortname = "ItemCode";
string sortorder = "asc";
string filter = "";
bool hasFilter = false;
if (Session["BudgetImportGridSettings"] != null)
{
    //
    // Get from cache the last page zise selected by the user.
    //
    Impetro.Models.Grid.GridSettings grid = (Impetro.Models.Grid.GridSettings)Session["BudgetImportGridSettings"];
    pageSize = grid.PageSize;
    sortname = grid.SortColumn;
    sortorder = grid.SortOrder;
    filter = grid.HasFilter ? grid.FilterString : "";
    hasFilter = grid.HasFilter && grid.Filter.rules.Count > 0;
}

}


<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


<br style="clear: both;" />
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
<span class="buttonspan backtolist" id="ReadExcel" title="Click to import budget line items from Excel"><a href="#" title="Click to import budget line items from Excel">Import</a></span>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<br style="clear: both;" />
<input type="checkbox" id="overwritefields" title="Overwrite other fields with imported non-blank data" class="chkclass" value=false />

<br style="clear: both;" />
<br style="clear: both;" />

@Html.Partial("_BudgetImportGrid")
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.BudgetType" id="IntBudgetType" />
```

Comment: See my answer, let me know if you want me to suggest other ways.. hth

Comment: I wasn't able to use FormData like you did...! So I used FileReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do it is just to add the `bool mode` to the action method:

```
public ActionResult ReadFromExcel(bool Mode)
{
    //Use the selected Mode...

    var file = Request.Files[0].
    // file contains the correct value.
    // Unable to retrieve mode value though.
}
```

Comment: How do I pass Mode parameter to the server side?

Comment: By using the ASP .NET MVC Framework! ;) The binding is done automatically by the framework: it looks into the request (searching from QueryString, Form data, ajax data, etc)...

Comment: So just include your Mode <input/> with the ajax data.

Comment: I added the Mode parameter to the action method and append the value to the form data (var overwritefields = $("#overwritefields").is(":checked");
                formData.append("Mode", overwritefields);). request return error:500. is there any changes required for url: 'ReadFromExcel'?

Comment: Is the server error about a bool Mode cannot accept value null? This means it wasn't able to find your Mode param. You can test this by changing bool Mode to bool? Mode

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use the HTML5 File Reader API. The following solution uses it:

I've built your scenario from scratch to make sure that my suggestions work.

Summary:

1. `bool mode` as action method parameter. It is provided to the server using Query String.
2. File uploaded as part of the request body as binary. The binary data is obtained using FileReader HTML5 API. This is the obly HTML5 part, if you can replace it, then you might get of the HTML5 dependency.
3. The AJAX is a POST request!

Use the following JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#upload").click(function () {
        var overwritefields = $("#overwritefields").is(":checked");

        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'UploadFileWithBoolean?mode=' + overwritefields,
                data: r.result,
                contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
                processData: false,
                success: function (d) {
                    console.log("ok");
                    console.log(d);
                },
                error: function (d) {
                    console.log("fail");
                    console.log(d);
                },
                async: true
            });
        };
        r.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0]);
    });
});
```

The controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFileWithBoolean(bool mode)
{
    //your file is now in Request.InputStream
    return Json(new { message = "mode is " + mode.ToString(), filesize = Request.InputStream.Length });
}
```

Let me know if this helps or not. Thanks